# Smart TV LG app, how to add content rating procedure

Tags: webos, lg, smart-tv

Right now i'm working on a VOD app for SmartTV recently some of the content was marked as 18+ so i need a way to invoke the LG parental pin input window. My problem is that while searching for such method im always redirected to the how to set the parental pin for tv channels. Does anyone know where can i search for the right method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement your own parental control flow inside your application.

LG Safety Password works only for Web0S flows before entering your app, like block some Apps, block some channels (cable input) or external devices via input locks.

To get an idea how your flow should work and how LG QA team is going to check it, you can check documents_for_app_qa.zip (section Adult authentication) from this link - https://webostv.developer.lge.com/design/ux-checklist/